# Get index info in postgres using Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, orm, django-orm

I'm using Postgres with Django and I want to get the info of an index I made on a table, specifically I want to see the size of the index.

Answer (score 2):

If you can do it on SQL then you can do it using the cursor:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

```py
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT pg_size_pretty (pg_indexes_size('mytable'));")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```